# Why would a Bounding Sphere and BoundingBox not intersect (when they should)?

Tags: xna, c#, collision-detection

I have a bounding sphere and a bounding box that should be intersecting, however, `Intersects(...)` is returning `false`. For example, the following returns false:

```
new BoundingSphere(new Vector3(500, 105, 0), 25).Intersects(
    new BoundingBox(new Vector3(466,219,0), new Vector3(519,26,0))
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.boundingbox.boundingbox.aspx

The constructor of BoundingBox expects minimum and maximum points. Your second vector's y is less than your first vector's y. This might break the intersection test.

Comment: No might about it. It will break it and that is the problem. Good answer.

Comment: True enough. That was it. A silly issue, and the one I haven't noticed because I still think of y as going towards the bottom. Thanks.